# Cron permissions (root, usergroup) - could not open input file

Tags: cron, user-permissions

I have a server for which I have created a cron job "sendalerts" to users. Mind you this "sendalerts.php" should be runnable from two methods (via browser and also via a cron job)

So cron's job is to execute a php file which then sends the alerts out, something like this:

```
01 01 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxx/sendalerts.php
```

But it keeps failing with the log message:

```
Could not open input file: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxx/sendalerts.php
```

So I checked the file group and owner of "sendalerts.php" and realized it was "anothergroup" (since it was created through Plesk filemanager) for which "root" is not a member. I then deleted and recreated "sendalerts.php" from SSH with root. But this would not grant me access to running the same file in browser as I would sometimes want to (manually send the alerts).

Yet I get the same log error when cron tries to execute (`Could not open input file: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxx/sendalerts.php`)

Currently my possible solution would be:

to recreate the same file using Plesk filemanager and then add "root" user to the "anothergroup" group .
**But for this My QUESTION is : would that be a safe and secure thing to do? considering now the group "anothergroup" may have "root" user permissions (if im not wrong in my understanding)**

Scout for other better solutions, Please if anyone has a better solution to this please suggest/advise me on this.
Thanks,

boxmluh

Comment: how do you configure cron? which file?

Answer (score 1):

Adding root to said groups won't help as root should be able to access "anothergroup" GID owned files already.

Check the audit logs (some times located under `/var/log/audit/`) for any error message. For example SELinux  or Apparmor may be preventing root from reaching into your directory through cron.

Other possible explanations may be that the `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/xxx/` dir is located on an NFS share or the like, and root gets squashed? In that case I suggest you create a user who is a member of the "anothergroup" group and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put the command in the crontab of a user who is member of "anothergroup".

However, I am wondering, usually root can access anything, why not here?

In any case, making root member of "anothergroup" won't hurt either. There's nothing on a system that is "run as the group". Stuff is only run as a user which is a member of group(s).